# Why is the metric of a Riemannian manifold required to be symmetric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, bilinear-form

- As Lee Mosher pointed out int the comments, asymmetric metrics do naturally occur in some contexts. So it is definitely justified to wonder about the mathematical necessity of symmetry in the formulation of the theory of Riemannian manifolds (i.e. which theorems require symmetry).
- If we drop the assumption that $g$ is symmetric, then $g^{ij}$ is only the transpose of the actual inverse of $g_{ij}$, but this doesn't seem like a huge deal. I assume that there are other reasons for the requirement of symmetry. Is it needed for the existence of orthonormal bases? Is it needed for the uniqueness of the signature? If yes, why is the uniqueness of the signature important? Are there more reasons to require symmetry?

Comment: Well, because a metric is an inner product (smoothly varying from point to point), and an inner product is a symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: @Leonid Well, we do not consider an inner product in SR (the metric is not positive-definite). And even if we did, I am asking for the mathematical necessity of symmetry for formulating the theory of Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: You still have a pseudo metric in SR, the Minkowski metric; it's not positive definite but it is still symmetric and is still a symmetric bilinear form. Intuitively a metric $g$, when it acts on 2 vectors $v,w$, should yield the projection of $v$ onto $w$, but you want that to also be equivalent to projecting $w$ onto $v$, wouldn't you agree? Hence the symmetry of the metric.

Comment: Basically the theory of Riemannian manifolds is intuitively a theory of smooth manifolds where we also have notions of angles and lengths, and for such a structure to exist you need an inner product which is in particular a symmetric bilinear form. You could ask for other types of bilinear forms such as a symplectic form, then you get a totally different structure and it turns out this structure is exactly what Hamiltonian mechanics is all about. So it's really a matter of what you are intuitively looking to describe.

Comment: In linear algebra, if you want to define the "angle" between two vectors $u$ and $v$, then you need a symmetric bilinear form.  In differential geometry, if you want to define the "angle" between two tangent vectors $u$ and $v$ at a point in a manifold, then you need a smoothly varying symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Asymmetric metrics have been around for a while, because they do naturally occur in some contexts. There do seem to be a few papers that give some generalities of their theory.

Comment: For instance searching *asymmetric Finsler metrics* on Google, the first hit I got was [this paper on asymmetric Finsler metrics](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.2478/agms-2013-0004/html).

Comment: So there is no "mathematical necessity" for Riemannian manifolds. One might nonetheless wish to take into consideration their astonishing success ;-)

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the comments, they further motivate my question. However, I thought that symmetry is at least necessary for the uniqueness of the signature: That's proposition 2.65 ("Sylvesters Law of Inertia") in [Lee's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-91755-9) and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) it seems to require symmetry. I am not sure though.

Comment: As @Leonid says, Riemannian metrics are meant to be generaizations of the dot product. The dot product has lots of nice properties. In particular, it encodes very simply the axioms and theorems of Euclidean geometry. These properties, restricted to the tangent space of a manifold, lead to lots of nice properties of Riemannian manifolds. The breadth and depth of the study of Riemannian geometry, especially the connections to topology, more than justifies our focus on them..

Comment: N.b. we can decompose a general bilinear form $h_{ij}$ into its symmetric and skew-symmetric parts, respectively, $h_{ij} = h_{(ij)} + h_{[ij]}$. Provided that $h_{(ij)}$ is nondegenerate, $h_{ij}$ defines a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric $h_{(ij)}$ and a (possibly degenerate) skew form $h_{[ij]}$, i.e., a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric with (if $h_{[ij]} \neq 0$, i.e., if $h_{ij}$ is not symmetric) additional structure.

Comment: That said, there is nothing stopping anyone from studying asymmetric metrics. I am sure there are mathematicians who have done so. Why they have not gained as much attention so far is probably mostly due to the fact that we have lost the connection to Euclidean geometry and it isn't clear what makes them compelling to study, It seems to me that if you want to study asymmetric metrics, you should start with the flat asymmetric metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and study its properties (geodesics, connection, submanifolds, etc.). If that is sufficiently interesting, move on to manifolds.

Comment: We also use symmetry of the metric to give an expression for Riemannian connection coefficients. That is, to arrive at: $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_ig_{jl}-\partial_l g_{ij}+\partial_j g_{li})$. Without this assumption, I'm not sure the same result follows.

Comment: This is a "why" question about a definition, which arguably is not about mathematics in the sense of Math.SE. Could it be phrased more specifically along the lines of your posted answer, e.g., "What geometric concepts can be defined in a finite-dimensional real vector space using a non-symmetric bilinear form?" or "What geometric concepts can be defined in a manifold equipped with a field of non-symmetric real bilinear forms in the tangent spaces?"

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang said "This is a 'why' question about a definition, which arguably is not about mathematics in the sense of Math.SE." - Well, we often have the situation where a definition involves more requirements than are needed for the definition to make sense. This is usually the case because we want to state a collection of important theorems without having to repeat the same requirement over and over again. So I think that it is often natural to ask why a definition involves certain requirements in order to understand the motivation.

Comment: To clarify, I agree that it's natural to ask about what conclusions change when hypotheses (such as symmetry of a Riemannian metric) are dropped, it just looks to me that this question as stated has no concise, definitive answer.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang said "I agree that it's natural to ask about what conclusions change when the symmetry of the Riemannian metric is dropped" - I think this summarizes the question very well :)

Answer (score 1):

We definitely need symmetry to prove the existence of an orthonormal basis: If an orthonormal basis exists, then the corresponding Gram matrix is symmetric and thus the bilinear form is symmetric.